# why the current working path is the initial path in shell "$()"

Tags: linux, shell

When I execute the following command：

```
[root@localhost install_zone]# su nylws -c "cd ~/gamesvr/conf;echo $(pwd);pwd"
```

The output:

```
/opt/deploy_scripts/install_zone 
/data/nylws/gamesvr/conf
```

So why the two paths are different? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `$(...)` is evaluated inside the double quotes by the parent shell, before the shell invoked by `su` is even started. So the subshell sees:

```
cd ~/gamesvr/conf;echo /opt/deploy_scripts/install_zone;pwd
```

The best way to fix this is to use single quotes, which will pass the string literally to the subshell and not do any expansion on it:

```
su nylws -c 'cd ~/gamesvr/conf;echo $(pwd);pwd'
```